# Socket io ip address is returning ::1

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ngrok

I'm trying to get the Client's IP Address from Socket IO and when I type

```
console.log(socket.conn.remoteAddress)
```

It returns `::1`

Comment: It's because this socket is on your localhost. If you try it in production, you'll see a real ip.

Comment: @i.brod But the client is not localhost im using ngrok

Comment: i see...don't know then.

Comment: Are you sure that socket.conn.remoteAddress returns the client ip and not the actual remote address that you are connected to? Could you try adding the --host-header=localhost to your command.

Comment: @BosnianCoder Yes I'm sure, where should i add that?

Comment: Ngrok is basically forwarding your localhost connection to the outside world, the reason you are getting ::1 could be because the remoteAddress might actually be the address of the server and not the IP address of the client itself. ::1 is the same as localhost or 127.0.0.1. This means its your computer, your host. Actually if you open 127.0.0.1:4040 this will display the ngrok dashboard, any new requests that appear from your client(s) should appear on that list, and by clicking on it you should see their IP address at the top right corner of the page. Check this code: tinyurl.com/socketio-ip

Comment: You add --host-header=localhost when running ngrok.

ngrok <connection> <port> --host-header=localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
socket.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for'].split(',')[0]
```

worked for me

Comment: This works correctly in PROD, but not in DEV.